# pm2 start in subdirectory

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a script in `package.json` like this. To run with npm I would just do it with `npm start`.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "cd build && node main"
}
```

I am currently trying to setup a pm2 config file for this. I created a `ecosystem.json` file. Neither of both of the following work with `pm2 ecosystem` command. What am I doing it wrong?

Note that it work if i manually type `cd build && pm2 start main.js` in command but this is not something i want.

First configuration:

```
{
    "apps": [{
        "name": "my-app",
        "cwd": "build",
        "script": "main.js"
    }]
}
```

Second configuration

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "my-app",
            "script": "npm",
            "args" : "start"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are giving the path incorrectly.

Use following instructions:

1. Hit `pm2 ecosystem` command, this will create a new file by name **ecosystem.config.js**
2. Remove all the code from the file and add the following code.

   ```
   module.exports = {
     apps : [
       {
         name      : 'API',
         script    : 'build/main.js',
       }
     ]
   };
   ```
3. Hit `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`
4. Check the logs using `pm2 logs`, your app will be started.

Hope this helps you.